# C# linq remove all element in a collection OfType<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I want to write something like that :

```
ICollection<BaseClass> collection;
collection.OfType<A>().Remove();
```

**EDIT**: A is a class that inherits from the BaseClass (A : BaseClass)

Any suggestion?

Comment: Suggestion: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - prepare some data and show what you tried and what did not work. Especially how `A` and `UserAccess` relate - and why you not use whatever enumerable Remove might return.

Comment: think it though. The method on the right hand side of the `.` is called from the object that is on the leftside of it. So `.OfType<A>()` will result in an own collection of items which is independent from `collection`.

Comment: but the most important thing is that `Remove` is not defined for `IEnumerable`. So this code should not compile. Have you actually tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try removing elements based on their types, like this:

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    List<IIntf> list = new List<IIntf>()
    {
      new AClass(),
      new BClass(),
    };

    list.RemoveAll(i => i.GetType() == typeof(BClass));
  }
}

public interface IIntf { }
public class AClass : IIntf { }
public class BClass : IIntf { }
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was possible AND simple. It works perfectly